# Groovy template map

Tags: dictionary, groovy

I am trying to build a groovy script which reads the json file

```
"Std": { "isAbstract": true, "jdk": "8", "mvn": "3.5.4" },  
"StdInstall": { "isAbstract": true, "inherits": ["Std"], "mvnCmd": "clean install" }, 
"StdDeploy": { "isAbstract": true, "inherits": ["Std"], "mvnCmd": "clean deploy" }, 
"WDF2": { "isAbstract": true, "svn": "http://..." },
"WDF2_install": { "inherits": ["WDF2", "StdInstall"] },
"WDF2_deploy": { "inherits": ["WDF2", "StdDeploy"] }
```

and tries to create a new map which replace all the inherits keys with the right values from the sam map 
for example the json would look like this in the output

```
"Std": { "isAbstract": true, "jdk": "8", "mvn": "3.5.4" },
"StdInstall": { "isAbstract": true, "jdk": "8", "mvn": "3.5.4", "mvnCmd": "clean install" },
"StdDeploy": { "isAbstract": true, "jdk": "8", "mvn": "3.5.4", "mvnCmd": "clean deploy" },  
"WDF2": { "isAbstract": true, "svn": "http://..." }, 
"WDF2_install": { "isAbstract": true, "svn": "http://...", "jdk": "8", "mvn": "3.5.4", "mvnCmd": "clean install" },

"WDF2_deploy": { "isAbstract": true, "svn": "http://...", "jdk": "8", "mvn": "3.5.4", "mvnCmd": "clean deploy" }
```

Thereby replacing all the inherits keys with right values from the same map and removing duplicates .

I came up with first bit of the code but couldnt proceed further

```
def result = new LinkedHashMap(temp)

temp.each{ k, v ->
v.each{
k1,v1 -> 
if(k1 == "inherits" ){ 
    v1.each{ val->
    val = temp[val]
    println k

    def new1= v+val
    println new1
      //result = v+temp[v2] 
      //println result
    } 


} 
} 
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: your structure supports nested `inherits`. better to create function that returns parameters of one key and if required recursively calls itself to extract inherited parameters... like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure others will find better solutions, but so far I came up with this:

```
def result = temp.collectEntries {k,v ->
  if (v instanceof Map) {
    v = new HashMap(v)
    (v.remove("inherits")?:[]).each {ref -> v << temp[ref]}
  }
  [(k):v]
```

}​

Somehow I was not able to get rid of the instanceof... Anyway.. the basic idea is that the json read in results in a Map (if you use Groovy JSON this is surely the case). collectEntries will create a new map out of an old one by providing maps for each entry, or map entries. I chose maps. v << temp[ref] will add all entries of the map found under temp[ref] to v. v.remove("inherits") removes the inherits entry, but also gives me the value the map had for this before. v.remove("inherits")?:[] ensures I will always get a non-null list, even if the entry does not exist. If it exist I expand the map with the "each", if not, nothing happens. Finally I build a new "map partial" with [(k):v], which takes the value of k for the key and the value of v for the value of my partial. [k:v] would create a map with a key named k instead.

Of course this can be easily extended to work recursively if required:

```
def replacer
replacer = {k,v ->
  if (v instanceof Map) {
    v = new HashMap(v)
    (v.remove("inherits")?:[]).each {ref -> v << temp[ref]}
    v = v.collectEntries replacer
  }
  [(k):v]
}
def result = temp.collectEntries replacer
```

EDIT: corrected version due to comment:

```
def result = temp.collectEntries {k,v ->   
  if (v instanceof Map) {
    v = new HashMap(v)
    def inherits = []
    while (true) {
      inherits +=  v.remove("inherits")?:[]
      if (!inherits) break
      v << temp[inherits.pop()]
    }
  }
  [(k):v] 
}
```

with Groovy 3 you could also use a do-while...

Comment: Thanks for the quick input . I only have one problem that is the key Std is not expanded to its new value when reused  output:    [Std:[jdk:8, mvn:3.5.4, isAbstract:true], StdDeploy:[jdk:8, mvn:3.5.4, isAbstract:true, mvnCmd:clean deploy], StdInstall:[jdk:8, mvn:3.5.4, isAbstract:true, mvnCmd:clean install], WDF2:[isAbstract:true, svn:http://...], WDF2_deploy:[svn:http://..., isAbstract:true, inherits:[Std] mvnCmd:clean deploy], WDF2_install:[svn:http://..., isAbstract:true, inherits:[Std], mvnCmd:clean install]]

Comment: oh, oversight of mine... too bad... well then let me correct the answer: